# Can't get async functions to work in simple NodeJS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

So, NodeJS newbie here - please be gentle. ;)

The below code runs fine in a modern browser:

```
async function testAsync(){
    return await new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('Hello World!');
        }, 1000)

    })
}

const test = await testAsync();
console.log(test);
```

It waits for 1000ms until printing "Hello World!" to the console, as expected.

Running Node 10.3.0 using the same code I get:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your call in a self invoking async function `void async function() { const test = await testAsync(); console.log(test); }();` (or use the returned promise)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't `await` on the top level (yet) as you're trying to do with `await testAsync();`. Instead, use `.then`:

```
testAsync()
  .then(test => console.log(test));
```

Also, there isn't much point having an `async` function that returns an `await`ed Promise immediately; instead, just return the Promise:

```js
function testAsync(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve('Hello World!');
    }, 1000)
  });
}
testAsync()
  .then(test => console.log(test));
```